# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an error `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error` with the code below:

```
private object ViewProgramDetails(Func<string, JsonResult> GetPrograms,string epicid)
{
    try
    {
        var path = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProgramDetailsUrl"] + "?epicid=" + epicid;

        XElement elem = XElement.Load(path);

        var inputheaderdictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> xmlDatadictionary = elem.Attributes().ToDictionary(attribute => attribute.Name.ToString().ToUpper(), attribute => attribute.Value);

        List<string> elementList = (from InputHeaderElements val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(InputHeaderElements)) select val.ToString().ToUpper()).ToList();

        foreach (string ele in elementList)
        {
            if (xmlDatadictionary.ContainsKey(ele))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!ele.ToUpper().Equals("EPIC") && !ele.ToUpper().Equals("EEQU"))
                    {
                        inputheaderdictionary.Add(ele, xmlDatadictionary[ele]);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }

        var result = inputheaderdictionary.ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown from the line below:

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load(path);
```

What can I do to fix this error? Or at least to have a better idea about the exact cause?

Comment: Can you verify that your `path` is not invalid/incorrect? For example, use `Console.WriteLine()` or `MessageBox.Show()` to display and check `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProgramDetailsUrl"]` as well as `epicid` and `path`, during runtime, and check if your path is being constructed correctly.

Comment: ya it is correct one

Comment: Apparently, according to this link, [LINQ XElement.load method not working correctly with strings withperiods in them](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/813171-linq-xelement-load-method-not-working-correctly-strings-withperiods-them), sometimes the URL parser won't recognize some periods or commas. You could try `var path = 
 String.Format( WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProgramDetailsUrl"] + "?epicid={0}", epicid);`

Comment: What is the exact error message you have in the Exception you catch?